# Django replaces non-ascii characters with \ufffd

Tags: django, unicode

Within my project, when I am submitting some data with non-ascii characters to the form, I am getting all non-ascii data replaced with unicode replacement character \ufffd. In the view that receives the data from the form, I have this malformed strings in request.POST. Seems I've missed something obvious.

My environment:

- Python 2.6
- Django 1.3 alpha 1
- MySQL 5.1, database uses UTF-8 charset

Have reproduced this issue using development server locally and intermediate server running Apache+mod_wsgi, with Firefox 4 and Chrome 11.

Where should I look to workout the problem? Thanks.

**Update:** below is the code I am using -

```
@render_to('mail/new_message.html')
@login_required
def new_message(request, user_id):
    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # exclude attachment from init instance, because we need instance id
        # for saving attachment
        form._meta.exclude = ['attachment']
        if form.is_valid():
            new_msg = form.save()
            new_msg.sender = user
            if form.cleaned_data['attachment']:
                new_msg.attachment = form.cleaned_data['attachment']
            new_msg.save()
            message_sent.send(sender=None,instance=new_msg)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(messages))
    else:
        initial = {}
        if user_id:
            initial['receivers'] = [user_id,]
        form = MessageForm(initial=initial)
    return {'form': form}
```

Comment: Have updated my question with the code, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** I forgot to add encoding to HTML pages I am generating. Adding of `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` solved the problem.

Comment: Is there any more to elaborate on this? I'm getting the same error, but I *do* have the charset set in the HTML :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the magic! [smart_unicode from Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions) should help you a lot. Mix between smart_unicode and smart_str regarding if you want to encode or decode a string (for any later project ;)).